# Open Access Database Table and set Cursor to field

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop, ms-access-2003

I am opening an access database table and would like to select a specific field in a table, so that the user can only start typing to change it.

I can already successfully open the appropriate table

```
Access.Application oAccess = null;

oAccess = new Access.Application();


oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(
     System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(fileToOpen),
     true //Exclusive
);

oAccess.DoCmd.OpenTable(tableToOpen);

oAccess.Visible = true;
```

Now I tried to search for a record, but this doesn`t work at all:

```
oAccess.DoCmd.SearchForRecord(Access.AcDataObjectType.acActiveDataObject, fileToOpen, Access.AcRecord.acFirst, @"[ID]='5'");
```

Say `tableToOpen = letterTable` which contains the column `recipients`. How would I **mark/select/highlight** the entire text in the field with `ID = 20` in the column `recipients` with the cursor?

This is not about querying data, it`s about opening the access application at a specific position for easing the manual editing process for the user.

Comment: Is this for an addin?

Comment: @Brad No, I generate the access database in C# before and I will guide the user to incorrect fields.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your requirement, but why not use ADO.Net instead of interop. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx) is a simple walk through

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958919/how-to-query-ms-access-database-with-c-sharp-application) is a stackoverflow answer linking to same MSDN Link i shared above.

Comment: I don`t want to edit the data at this location, I want to open the actual access application at one specific position (where the error happened). The user will then review the table manually.