# How do I check to see if Data exists in an access database

Tags: c#

How do I see if data exists in a database from an access database in my C# program and and a message box that shows "word exists in a the database".

This is what I have so far:

```
private void check_word_exists_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StopWordsDataSet.StopWordsRow wordsRow = stopWordsDataSet.StopWords.FindByword(query_word.Text);
    if (query_word.Text = )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop word exists");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stop word doesn't exists");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query MS Access database with C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958919/how-to-query-ms-access-database-with-c-sharp-application)

Comment: You are the only one who can answer that as you know the implementation of `FindByword`. What does it return if it finds a word? Do a `Console.WriteLine(wordsRow);` and you probably know.

Comment: thank you rene for that i got it

Answer (score 0):

i was almost there but i can found out how to do it

```
private void check_word_exists_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopWordsDataSet.StopWordsRow wordsRow = stopWordsDataSet.StopWords.FindByword(query_word.Text);
        try
        {
            if (query_word.Text == wordsRow.word)
            {
                query_word.Text = query_word.Text;
                MessageBox.Show("Stop word '"+ query_word.Text + "' exists");
                query_word.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Stop word doesn't exists");
            }
        }catch(Exception)
        {
            query_word.Text = query_word.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Stop word '"+ query_word.Text + "' doesn't exists");
            query_word.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

thank you for your help guys