# Execute query and populate the same in datagrid Box

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, winforms

I have a winform app connected to access database as data source ,

but in access i was using this below SQL to generate a query table  called trend:

```
TRANSFORM Count(Complaint_Number) AS [Total Numbers]
SELECT Nature_of_problem, Count(Complaint_Number) AS [Total Numbers of Issues]
FROM master_table
GROUP BY Nature_of_problem
PIVOT Format(Complaint_Received_On,"mmm") In ("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
```

But i do not know how execute this & populate the same in datagrid box on form load event(dataset:CSCdataset) , please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can find more information on your question here:
[How to query MS Access database with C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958919/how-to-query-ms-access-database-with-c-sharp-application)
This post refers to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms971485(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

In my winform-app, I use an SQL Server. It is probably somehow the same procedure for an Access database:

```
            using System.Data.SqlClient;
            
            //open connection
            //cnnString = $@"Data Source=<yourServer>;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=<yourDatabase>
            SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(@cnnString);
            cnn.Open();
            
            //execute query
            string exec = $@"<your query>";
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(exec, cnn);
            adapter.Fill(dataSet); //fill dataset
            cnn.Dispose();

            //read dataset
            dataSet.Tables[0].Rows ...
```

You can enhance this code by putting cnn into a using statement, like so:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
       connectionString)) {
    try {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        //log and/or rethrow or ignore
    }
}
```

Source: [The C# using statement, SQL, and SqlConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079098/the-c-sharp-using-statement-sql-and-sqlconnection)

To bind a DataTable to a DataGridView, just assign the DataTable to the DataSource Property of the DataGridView, like so:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable;
```

I hope I helped you a little with my answer.
Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much ...you certainly helped me a lot

Comment: Glad I could help, leave me an upvote if you like :)